# transfer okular annotations to extended pdf

Tags: okular, xml, viewports

I have an `OLD.pdf` annotated using `okular`. I also have a `NEW.pdf`, which is the `OLD.pdf` without anotations plus an extra chapter in the end.

**How can I transfer the annotations from the `OLD.pdf` to the `NEW.pdf`?**

I want to be able to edit, using `okular`, the annotations that `NEW.pdf` has from the `OLD.pdf`.

By the way I think annotations are stored in `~/.local/share/okular/docdata/` but I have no clue what to do. These numbers in the names of the files are a mystery to me.

I have no clue what the viewport value does. Where is the text of my annotations?

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is to merge the annotated OLD.pdf with the extra part of the NEW.pdf . Then I opened the resulting file with okular and the annotations where there and I could  edit them . That worked at least for me .